# What would make offsetParent null?

Tags: javascript, html, positioning

I am trying to do positioning in JavaScript.  I am using a cumulative position function based on the [classic quirksmode function](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) that sums `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` for each `offsetParent` until the top node.

However, I am running into an issue where the element I'm interested in has no `offsetParent` in Firefox.  In IE `offsetParent` exists, but `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` all sum up to 0, so it has the same problem in effect as in Firefox.

What would cause an element that is clearly visible and usable on the screen to not have an `offsetParent`? Or, more practically, how can I find the position of this element in order to place a drop-down beneath it?

**Edit**: Here's how to reproduce one particular instance of this (not solved by the currently-accepted answer):

1. Open the [home page of Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).
2. Run the following code in the Console of the web browser (e.g. Chromev21):

   ```js
   var e = document.querySelector('div');
   console.log(e);
   // <div id="notify-container"></div>
   do{
     var s = getComputedStyle(e);
     console.log(e.tagName,s.display,s.visibility,s.position,e.offsetParent);
   } while(e=e.parentElement)
   // DIV block visible fixed null
   // BODY block visible static null
   // HTML block visible static null
   ```

**Why is the `offsetParent` of that element `null`?**

Comment: Please post some sample code.

Comment: A real world example showing the faulty element would help...

Comment: In your case, it's because of `position:fixed` - there is no layout parent

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the document hasn't finished loading then offsetParent can be null

Answer (score 51):

I have made [a test of 2,304 divs](http://jsfiddle.net/XEHZV/3/) with unique combinations of values for `position`, `display`, and `visibility`, nested inside unique combinations of each of those values, and determined that:

an otherwise-valid element
that is a descendant of `<body>`
will not have an `offsetParent` value if:

- The element has `position:fixed` (*Webkit and IE9*)
- The element has `display:none`   (*Webkit and FF*)
- Any ancestor has `display:none`  (*Webkit and FF*)

*It is also reasonable to expect that an element that has no parent, or that is not added to the page itself (is not a descendant of the `<body>` of the page), will also have `offsetParent==null`.*

Comment: Thank you very much, you answer made me understand why this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/21696585/4481831 worked in FF but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 13):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetParent

offsetParent returns null when the element has style.display  set to "none".

Comment: Per my answer below, I've now edited the MDN page to note that there are other situations for non-FF browsers that also cause the situation.

Comment: is not as simple as you say it. offsetParent will also return null if style.display is for example "block" but one of the element parents style.display is "none". that why this method is used for checking the visibility of an element better then "getComputedStyle" method that do not check for parents.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I have another case.  If you manipulate the DOM, you may end up with a null offsetParent - in IE6 and IE7.

See: [IE 6/7 - "Unspecified Error" when accessing offsetParent (Javascript)](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/11/29/ie-6-7-unspecified-error-when-accessing-offsetparent-javascript.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`offsetParent` will return null if your element object hasn't been appended to the DOM yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem when the sibling just to the left of the element is hidden:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="element1">some stuff</div>
  <div id="element2" style="display: none">some hidden stuff</div>
  <div id="element3">child whose offset we want</div>
</div>
```

I've run into the case where the **offsetParent** of **element3** is null even though **element3** itself is visible, and **parent** is visible.

I've seen thin is Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 5.  It seems to also affect the **getBoundingClientRect()** function on the **element3**, which is really annoying since that works in so many other cases!

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced an `offsetParent` of `null` when the parent was inside a web component (i.e. the element I tried getting the `offsetParent` of was projected into the web component).