# offsetParent() in jQuery not returning expected relative-positioned ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery, positioning, offset

I have some HTML with the following approximate structure and positioning:

```
<div class="grand-parent" style="position: absolute">
  <div class="parent" style="position: relative">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my jQuery widget, I'm trying to insert an element that is located inside the "offset parent" of the element targeted by the widget.  To do so, I essentially have code like this:

```
var targetElement = $('.child');
$('<div/>').appendTo(targetElement.offsetParent());
```

Unfortunately, the element appears to be inserted as a child of `.grand-parent` instead of `parent`.  My understanding of `offsetParent()` (and the documentation seems to back this) is that `offsetParent()` should return `.parent` because it is positioned relative.  Is my understanding of offsetParent incorrect, or is there  a problem with jQuery (I'm using 1.4.1).

Comment: I noticed you are appending to "this.element.offsetParent()".  What is this in relation to targetElement?  Your usage of offsetParent and appendTo seem valid, so maybe the problem is with your usage of "this" or a problem with the code before you simplified it?

Comment: What's the context of "this" in `this.element.offsetParent()`?

Comment: Oops... corrected.  Sorry.  Should be `targetElement.offsetParent()`

Comment: @Jacob, but it works with `targetElement.offsetParent()`.. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/2y53y/1/

Comment: I got the same results as Gaby - the code from the question works.

Comment: Doesn't for me... I should mention that the `position` properties are not inline but are declared in a CSS file (in case it matters).

Comment: Your jquery coding looks good - I would be sure you are referencing the right elements with your selectors in both CSS and jQuery.  Firebug is handy for this.

Comment: Still fine if you relocate the styling to CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/2y53y/3/

Comment: I think I found the contributing factor (which I failed to post).  `.parent` was also set to `display: none`.  If it's set to `display: block`, then `offsetParent()` returned the correct element.  Is that documented somewhere that display mode affects offsetParent?

Comment: Found the answer to that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetParent, courtesy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306305/what-would-make-offsetparent-null/3877473#3877473.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetParent, `offsetParent` doesn't work as I had expected if the parent is not displayed (`display: none`).  In my case, the container element is just that.

Comment: I had the same issue, but it was because the element I was getting an offset parent for was invisible.  It was at least affecting me in Webkit.  Didn't try other browsers.